How to correct for Hansen-Hodrick standard error as Campbell & Shiller (1991) using R?
I am trying to replicate the Campbell & Shiller (1991) paper using Brazilian data.
My data consists of the following. Each line is a triple $(n,m,t)$, where $n$ is the maturity of the bond, $m$ is a divisor of the maturity $n$ (is a shorter maturity) and $t$ is the mounth when the interest rate was calculated. For each line, I have:

$y^{(n)}_t$: interest rate at $t$ of a $n$-period zero coupom bond;
$y^{(m)}_t$: interest rate at $t$ of a $m$-period zero coupom bond;
$y^{(n-m)}_{t+m}$: interest rate at $t+m$ of a $n-m$-period zero coupom bond;
$\sum_{i=1}^k \left(1-\frac{i}{k}\right) \Delta^m y_{t+im}^{(m)}$: LHS of the second regression.

For each par $(n,m)$, I have run two regressions (that is, I split my data set for each par $(n,m)$ and run a regression for each piece):
$$y^{(n-m)}_{t+m}-y^{(n)}_t=\alpha^{(n,m)}+\beta^{(n,m)} \frac{m}{n-m} s_t^{(n,m)}+\epsilon_t^{(n,m)}$$
where $s_t^{(n,m)}=y^{(n)}_t-y^{(m)}_t$, and
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \left (1-\frac{i}{k}\right )( y^{(m)}_{t+im}-y^{(m)}_{t+(i-1)m})=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \left (1-\frac{i}{k}\right )\Delta^m y^{(m)}_{t+im}=\alpha^{(n,m)}+\beta^{(n,m)} s^{(n,m)}_t+\epsilon_t^{(n,m)}$$
As the paper does, I want to calculate ``asymptotic standard errors corrected for heteroskedasticity and equation error overlap in the manner of Hansen and Hodrick (1980) and White (1984)''. But I am not sure how to do it using R.
For the first regression, I have done:
feols(f_n_m_t_m-f_n~1+m_s, 
                 data=x,
                 vcov=function(x){kernHAC(x,kernel = "Truncated",bw=1,
                                         sandwich=FALSE,prewhite = FALSE, adjust = FALSE)}
                 )

Is this right? Can I use this type of correction when my data set is in that format?
I would like any help.
Source:
John Y Campbell and Robert J Shiller. Yield spreads and interest rate movements: A bird’s eye view. The Review of Economic Studies, 58(3):495–514, 1991.
